# Deserializing a single element in a large XML document: xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader.ReadSubtree()) fails due to namespace issues

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xmlreader, xmlserializer

I am attempting to process a large XML document (using a `XmlReader`) in a single pass, and deserialize only certain elements in it using an `XmlSerializer`.

Below is some code and a tiny mock XML document showing how I have attempted to do this.

> <sup>**Rationale for using `XmlReader`:** **1.** I am dealing with very large XML documents (10–250 MB), which for this reason I do not want to load into memory. So `XmlDocument` is out of the question. **2.** I want to extract only certain elements. Typically I will be able to ignore most other content. `XmlReader` appears to give me an efficient means of skipping irrelevant content. **3.** I do not know in advance whether any and all elements that I can deal with will be present; therefore I am not using a bunch of `Xpath`/`XQuery` or LINQ to XML-based queries, because I want to make only a single pass over the XML files (due to their size).</sup>

```
public class ElementOfInterest { }
…

var xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
            <Root xmlns:ex='urn:stakx:example'
                  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
              <ElementOfInterest xsi:type='ex:ElementOfInterest' />
            </Root>";

var reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
reader.ReadToFollowing("ElementOfInterest");

var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ElementOfInterest));
serializer.Deserialize(reader.ReadSubtree());
```

The last line of code throws the following inner exception:

> *`InvalidOperationException`: "Namespace prefix `ex` is not defined."*

Obviously, the `XmlSerializer` doesn't recognise the `ex` namespace prefix inside the `xsi:type` attribute's value.

This is just one error I am having, but frankly, the larger problem is that I have no idea how to go about the whole namespace issue. I am simply looking for a convenient way to de-serialize just a single node out of the XML document, but that seems to entail having to manually register/manage namespaces, and to somehow forward them from the `XmlReader` to the `XmlSerializer`.

Can someone demonstrate how to deserialize a single node from a XML document read with an `XmlReader`, either by pointing out the error in my code, or by showing an alternative approach?

Comment: Look for an example on `XmlNamespaceManager`. Here is [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14462578/815938) to start.

Comment: @kennyzx: I have looked at `XmlNamespaceManager`, and `XmlNameTable`, and `XmlParserContext`, and what not. I simply have no idea how it is supposed to fit together in my scenario. Could you please demonstrate its use for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

static void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
                <Root
                  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                  xmlns:ex='urn:stakx:example'
                >
                  <ex:ElementOfInterest xsi:type='ex:ElementOfInterest' />
                </Root>";

    var nt = new NameTable();
    var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
    mgr.AddNamespace("ex", "urn:stakx:example");
    var ctxt = new XmlParserContext(nt, mgr, "", XmlSpace.Default);
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), null, ctxt);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ElementOfInterest));

    reader.ReadToFollowing("ElementOfInterest", "urn:stakx:example");
    var eoi = (ElementOfInterest)serializer.Deserialize(reader.ReadSubtree());
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:stakx:example")]
public class ElementOfInterest { }
```

Note the namespace in the input: `<ex:ElementOfInterest>`.

Comment: Can you explain why you changed the input document (i.e. added the namespace prefix to the element)? Is it to make your code work, or because *my* version of the example input was not well-formed / invalid in some way?

Comment: Both, sort of. Well, your input document states that the resulting object should be in the `urn:stakx:example` namespace. Your target class `ElementOfInterest` did not reflect that, so adding the `XmlRoot(Namespace=...)` class attribute was the first change. Now, when you *serialize* an `ElementOfInterest` object again, the resulting XML element will also be in the `urn:stakx:example` namespace. In order to make deserialization and serialization symmetric, I had to put the element into that namespace in the input.